# How to wrap a function in a function to avoid code repetition

Tags: javascript

Using jQuery in this example, though that should have no bearing on the answer.

I have two events that fire on page load:

```
triggerEvent(SNVisitsForm); 
$('#email').blur(triggerEvent(SNEnterEmail));
```

The first simply fires when the user visits the page, and the other is a listener which will fire when the user blurs the email field.

`triggerEvent` is a function which I am using to "wrap" many disparate functions with one simple conditional. The goal is to have this conditional be able wrap any arbitrary function:

```
function triggerEvent(wrapped_function) {
if (typeof _cookie !== 'undefined') {
        wrapped_function();
        console.log('Doing the event, because the cookie is defined');
    }
}
```

That function works just fine for the first of the two examples (that is, (`triggerEvent(SNVisitsForm);` functions perfectly).

However, since `SNEnterEmail` starts like this:

```
function SNEnterEmail(event) {
    var email = event.target.value;
```

I need to pass the event through the wrapper function to the wrapped function. As you can see, sometimes an event doesn't exist (as in the case of the first of the two examples).

Is there a more "javascript" way to do this? Surely the answer isn't "just put that conditional code around every single one of your calls that need it" or "put it into every single function that needs it." What is the javascript-approved way to accomplish this avoidance of repetition?

Edit: I should add that the answer may well be something completely different from wrapping a function in a function. It was just the best way I could think to illustrate what I was trying to do.

**How the accepted answer solved this for me:**

I did use adrian's wrapper function, and then a quick modification to my calls made everything work:

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
    (triggerEvent(SNVisitsForm)()); 
}
$('#email').blur(triggerEvent(SNEnterEmail));
```

I'm not sure why adrian changed the wrapped functions to vars, I left them as functions. Then I simply make "standard" calls of the wrapper function (i.e., those that are not bound to listeners) Immediately Invoked Function Expressions.

Comment: What do you think `$('#email').blur(triggerEvent(SNEnterEmail));` does? (Be *super* specific and accurate)

Comment: @Amit: I think that line binds a listener to the blur event for the element selected by `#email`. When the blur event occurs for that element, a function called `triggerEvent` will be called with the parameter `SNEnterEmail`. That function will then check a conditional, at which point if the conditional is true `SNEnterEmail` will be called.

To say that again in less technical terms, when the user clicks off the email field, I'll make sure a cookie is enabled and then do the associated event if it is.

Comment: Well, just as I suspected... you've got that part wrong... what this line does is (in order..): 1. call `triggerEvent`, passing `SNEnterEmail` as a parameter. 2. tries to bind whatever that call returned **as a function** to the blur event, but there is no explicit return, which makes it `undefined` which means nothing is really bound to blur, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Amit thanks for clearing that up. With that understanding, and adrian's answer, I was able to get a working solution.

Comment: Just one thing is bothering me about your solution. You don't need to wrap `SNVisitsForm` if it's being called directly. It should be `if(window.location.pathname === '/') SNVisitsForm();`

Comment: @JonathanGray Except then SNVisitsForm won't respect the cookie if I don't wrap it, right? The whole reason I need the wrapper is to send that event only if the cookie conditional passes. In this case, not only does this unique "must be at root domain" conditional need to be true, but IN ADDITION the cookie conditional must be true.

Comment: @fildred13 Sorry my mistake you could use `if(window.location.pathname === '/' && typeof _cookie !== 'undefined') SNVisitsForm()`... Or you could check the condition inside of the function itself. Just seems weird to wrap a function and call it right away without parameters.

Comment: @JonathanGray In the context of this small example, yes you're absolutely right. In the context of the actual script (which has 20+ "SN..." functions, all of which have their own conditionals and such) it makes sense to wrap them all for readability and consistency.

Comment: @fildred13 Maybe, but in that specific case I would still just go with not wrapping it (because it's a method that gets called on page load and therefore is only called once and without parameters). Unless you're planning on changing the conditional at some point in the future (in which case it would be easier to have it in one place).

Comment: @JonathanGray I would argue that the entire value of this wrapper function is to unify all of these calls under one conditional which anyone could change in one place and have the confidence that all expected calls use the wrapper. There are many single calls with one or no conditionals, and no parameters. Duplicating the conditional for each of those makes for a maintenance...I won't say nightmare, because it's only one file and not that big yet. But some day it may be many files and many lines, and when that day comes I think we'll be glad that a single wrapper holds our 'master' conditional

Comment: Then it's easier just to say "I want it in one place"

Comment: I feel that "avoiding code repetition" and general coding principals make such a desire obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a function decorator that returns a function. closure will take care the rest.

```
function triggerEventWrapper(wrapped_function) {
 return function(){
   if (typeof _cookie !== 'undefined') { 
      console.log('Doing the event, because the cookie is defined');
      return wrapped_function.apply(this,arguments);
     }
 }
}


var SNEnterEmail = triggerEventWrapper(function(){
   ...... the function decloration
});
$('#email').blur(SNEnterEmail);


var  SNVisitsFormWrapped = triggerEventWrapper(SNVisitsForm); 
SNVisitsFormWrapped();
```

Comment: close, but no cigar. First line (`triggerEvent(SNVisitsForm); `) won't work

Comment: I added the usage. that should help.

Comment: No... it won't. You didn't pay attention to the question & my comment

Comment: See edits to question to see how I ended up using this answer.